# Oracle form builder trigger

Tags: oracle, formbuilder

I want add to my block text item where I display count of my all record:

code is:

```
BEGIN
    GO_ITEM('KIEKKAT');
    SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO :KATEGORIJA.KIEKKAT
  FROM  KATEGORIJA;
  END;
```

This wordk only if I choose trigger "WHEN-MOUSE-CLICK" ,but then all other items not display data. If I choose other trigger all items not displaying anything. i want tat this text item will all time display count of record. Please say me, how to do it, whicj trigger set I do my code if correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider a Summary item for this purpose - especially if you already have a block based on the KATEGORIJA table.

You add an item which is based on a COUNT from that block: set **Calculation Mode** to Summary, **Summary Function** to Count, and set **Summarized Block** to the block. Set the **Query All Records** property on the block to True.

Comment: Querying all records might get very slow specially if you have post-query triggers. Use this with caution.

Comment: @Roger - agreed, a `post-query` trigger could pose a significant problem. However, in these sorts of cases often there already is a block that shows the records, so adding a COUNT summary item adds no significant cost; and if the number of records is relatively low a post-query trigger would probably be alright as long as it doesn't issue additional queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try it on the POST-SELECT trigger at the block level.

From the documentation:

**Description**

The Post-Select trigger fires after the default selection phase of query processing, or after the successful execution of the On-Select trigger.  It fires before any records are actually retrieved through fetch processing.

**Usage Note:**

Use the Post-Select trigger to perform an action based on the outcome of the Select phase of query processing such as an action based on the number of records that match the query criteria.

Edit.

take a look at this
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=883340

You can get the number from a block property.